# Show/hide multiple divs with jquery and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to show/hide multiple divs using various checkboxes. I am targeting the class of the div which the CMS gives when the user chooses a category/categories.

This works fine with one class but as soon as multiple classes are given to one div they clash and it messes the whole thing up..

**HTML for the checkboxes**

```
    <ul class="checkboxes">
        <li class="dropper"><a href="#"><label>Project Management<input id="box1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkbox-01" /><span id="box1"></span></label></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><label>Copywriting<input id="box2" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkbox-02" /><span id="box2"></span></label></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><label>Design<input id="box3" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkbox-03" /><span id="box3"></span></label></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><label>Editing<input id="box4" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkbox-04" /><span id="box4"></span></label></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><label>Multimedia<input id="box5" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkbox-05" /><span id="box5"></span></label></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><label>Advertising<input id="box6" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkbox-06" /><span id="box6"></span></label></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><label>Consultancy<input id="box7" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkbox-07" /><span id="box7"></span></label></a></li>
        <li class="dropper"><a href="#"><span id="reset-toggles" class="reset">Reset</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

**HTML for the divs I want to show/hide**

```
<div class="box-shadow copywriting design editing">
  <div class="caption">
      <h3>Scottish Hosteler Magazine</h3>
      <h4>Scottish Youth Hostel Association</h4>
      <p><a href="case-study-L1.php">Find out more &gt; &gt;</a></p>
  </div>
  <img src="img/tile1.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="box-shadow copywriting design">
  <div class="caption">
      <h3>Scottish Dental Magazine</h3>
      <h4>Scottish Dental</h4>
      <p><a href="case-study-L2.php">Find out more &gt; &gt;</a></p>
  </div>
  <img src="img/tile2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**And jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#reset-toggles").click(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", !0);

  }), $("#box1").click(function() {
      $(".projman").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");

  }), $("#box2").click(function() {
      $(".copywriting").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");

  }), $("#box3").click(function() {
      $(".design").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");

  }), $("#box4").click(function() {
      $(".editing").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");

  }), $("#box5").click(function() {
      $(".multimedia").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");

  }), $("#box6").click(function() {
      $(".advertising").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
  });
});
```

So say the user wants to view divs with classes "design" and "copywriting" ONLY it will hide the top example as it also contains the class "editing"

Basically what I'm after is code to allow the combination to work i.e. if the user selects "design" and "copywriting" it will show ONLY the divs with those two classes and not ones with another class such as "editing" aswell

Very complicated and frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the unique ids of `#box1`, `#box2` etc to multiple elements, which is prohibited in HTML, use classes where you want to apply a reference to multiple elements.

In your case, I presume you want to apply your jQuery handlers to the checkbox elements, so try this:

```
<li class="dropper">
    <label for="box1">Project Management</label>
    <input id="box1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkbox-01">
</li>
```

- I removed the span as it was empty and duplicated a unique ID, and I removed the anchor tag as it was seemingly useless also.

Answer (score 0):

**filter, meet schmilter**

jquery:

```
var puts = $('.checkboxes input[type=checkbox]');//checkboxes
var cans = $('.box-shadow');//content blocks
var schmilt = true;//set false for filtering instead of schmiltering
function schmilter() {
    puts.each(function() {//get checkboxes
        var cl = $(this).attr('id');//get id
        if (this.checked) { $('.'+cl).addClass('show'); }//if checked show
        else { $('.'+cl).addClass('hide'); }//if !checked hide
        if (!$('.'+cl).length) { $(this).prop('checked',false).parent('li').hide(); }//if class doesn't exist uncheck/hide invalid options
    });
    cans.each(function() {//get all content blocks
        if(schmilt) {//if schmilt
            if($(this).hasClass('hide')) { $(this).fadeOut('fast').removeClass('hide show'); }//hide
            else if ($(this).hasClass('show')) { $(this).fadeIn('fast').removeClass('show'); }//show
        } else {//if !schmilt
            if($(this).hasClass('show')) { $(this).fadeIn('fast').removeClass('hide show'); }//show
            else if ($(this).hasClass('hide')) { $(this).fadeOut('fast').removeClass('hide'); }//hide   
        }
    });
}
schmilter();//initial run
puts.on('change', function() { schmilter(); });//on change run schmilter
$('#reset').on('click', function() {//click reset
    puts.prop('checked', true);//check all
    schmilter();//run schmilter
});
```

This will look at all checked/unchecked boxes, assign classes of `hide` and `show`. If a container has `hide`, then it is hidden and `hide` and `show` are removed. If it only has `show`, then it is shown and `show` is removed.

When you set `schmilt = false` then it will do the opposite and provide a typical filtering function.

It will also remove selections if they don't apply to any existing containers.

I reworked the html to make a little more sense, like @scrowler mentions, but took it a little further. I've added corresponding ids/classes between the checkboxes and the content. So if a checkbox has an id of `#edit` then the corresponded content containers all have a class of `.edit`

html:

```
<ul class="checkboxes">
    <li class="dropper">
        <label for="projman">Project Management</label>
        <input id="projman" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="projman" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="copywriting">Copywriting</label>
        <input id="copywriting" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="copywriting" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="design">Design</label>
        <input id="design" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="design" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="editing">Editing</label>
        <input id="editing" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="editing" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="multimedia">Multimedia</label>
        <input id="multimedia" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="multimedia" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="advertising">Advertising</label>
        <input id="advertising" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="advertising" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="consultancy">Consultancy</label>
        <input id="consultancy" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="consultancy" />
    </li>
    <li class="dropper"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="reset">Reset</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="box-shadow copywriting design editing">
    <div class="caption">
         <h3>Scottish Hosteler Magazine</h3>
         <h4>Scottish Youth Hostel Association</h4>
        <p><a href="case-study-L1.php">Find out more &gt; &gt;</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <img src="img/tile1.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="box-shadow copywriting design">
    <div class="caption">
         <h3>Scottish Dental Magazine</h3>
         <h4>Scottish Dental</h4>
        <p><a href="case-study-L2.php">Find out more &gt; &gt;</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <img src="img/tile2.jpg" />
</div>
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/4NS3A/